# How to pass list of quotated file names as a parameter to another script in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, pdf-generation

I am stuck with passing list of quoted file names that contain a space in their names to `pdfunite` in my script. It works in shell but not in my bash script.

**Prove of concept**

This way I collect all the file names of given pattern encapsulated with double quotation `"`:

```
# Collect quoted file names 
$ ls -x -Q "file"*.pdf
"file 01.pdf" "file 02.pdf" "file 03.pdf"

# Manually passed params in shell following the syntax: pdfunite <PDF-sourcefile-1>..<PDF-sourcefile-n> <PDF-destfile>
$ pdfunite "file 01.pdf"  "file 02.pdf" "file output.pdf"

# File is successfully created
$ ls "file output.pdf"
'file output.pdf'
```

**My script**

In my script I tried to collect the list of files in various ways but nothing works

```
# first approach - single line
pdfunite $(ls -x -Q "file"*.pdf) "file output.pdf"

# second approach - using variable
filesin=`ls -x -Q "file"*.pdf) "file output.pdf"`
pdfunite $filesin "file output.pdf"
```

**Error output from my script**

Both approaches above fails with following message from the `pdfunite`:

```
pdfunite '"file' '01.pdf"' '"file' '02.pdf"' 'file output' \
  I/O Error: Couldn't open file '"file': No such file or directory.
```

So what is the trick to pass the list of file names encapsulated with the quotation?

Comment: `pdfunite file*[0-9].pdf 'file output.pdf'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pdfunite file*.pdf 'file output.pdf'
```

or

```
pdfunite 'file '*.pdf 'file output.pdf'
```

Note that if `file output.pdf` exists it will be in the glob list, so it should not exist.

No word splitting occurs in a glob expansion, but it does for (an unquoted) command substitution. Parsing or otherwise using `ls` output in a script is usually a mistake. Glob expansion and `find` are better alternatives.

Edit: fixed typo in first example

Comment: Yeah, you are right @dan. There is no need to list the files using the `ls` before passing them to `pdfunite`. While writing my script I focused to proper listing the files which is actually contra productive in this case as you explained. So I have remove the `ls` part from my script and used your the first example. Thanks for the explanation!